# Erro na classe PHPMalier

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer, smtp, gmail

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês! Tenha a seguinte classe para enviar emails no php:

```
<?php
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'barussivendas@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'MinhSenha';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('lhbs1515@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('lhbs1515@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient


    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Mas estou recebendo a seguinte excessão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguem sabe do que se trata? Se é um erro interno aqui da rede, se a porta informada está incorreta ou bloqueada? Estou a tarde inteira nisso e nao consigo resolver!!

Comment: me explica  de onde saiu esse arquivo autoload.php `'PHPMailer/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: esse php autoload, é simples: abra o cmd, navegue até uma pasta, depois coloque isso: composer require phpmailer/phpmailer ele ira gerar um autoload.
Se voce nao conseguir executar, instale o composer no seu micro e tente novamente. Boa sorte! 
Link: https://packagist.org/packages/phpmailer/phpmailer

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver colocando o seguinte item:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array ( 
        'ssl' => array ( 
        'verify_peer' => false, 
        'verify_peer_name' => false, 
        'allow_self_signed' => true));
```

Muito Obrigado